# generate random locations nearby my location

Tags: android, geolocation, range

I would like to generate random latitude/longitude pairs inside the circle surrounding my location.

Currently i have implemented a location listener and everytime i get a new location i would like to draw random locations nearby me.

I am able to compute distance between 2 already existing locations and know if its inside my range:

```
public List<Location> filter(Location current, List<Location> locations, int radius) {
    List<Location> results = new ArrayList<Location>();
    for (Location loc : locations) {
        if (current.distanceTo(loc) <= radius) {
            results.add(loc);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

But really, i cant find how to generate locations inside my range.

Any help here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you keyser5053. That is the problem, i dont know how to generate the coordinates myself because i dont know the coordinates range to use.

Comment: you seem to know the radius. that's all you need.

Comment: yes, the radius is 100 meters. My problem is with the math involved, i will keep on thinking, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about randomly generating the coordinates yourself? Using the current location you could set limitations to these numbers. Using the current coordinates and the radius you get the span for the random numbers. Span for random new X = Old X +- radius

I'd suggest generating a random number between -1 and 1, then multiply it with the radius. This means that the max value for the generated coordinate is the radius (and min is -radius). Adding this value to the current location coordinate gives you a value between Old X +- radius. Summary:

**(Random number between -1 and 1)*radius + (old x) = new x within radius of old x.**

Example code for the random number (OBS! from 0 to 1):

```
import java.util.Random;

Random r = new Random();
double zeroToOne = r.nextInt(1001) / 1000
```

Here's the java documentation on random: [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: I think i get the point now, thank you very much, going to give it a try.

Comment: @pindleskin edited formula so that it doesn't just give you new coordinates larger than the old ones (span from -1)

Answer (score -1):

it seems like a good thing. if you want to take a look : http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/get-list-of-address-from-location-using.html

i think, normally it have been working but i couldn't try to setup it on device