# Wrong distances when creating random locations

Tags: android, geolocation, range, distance

I am trying to create random locations nearby my location. What i want is to create random latitude/longitude pairs inside a 200 meters circle surrounding my location. After asking this question: [generate random locations nearby my location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530031/generate-random-locations-nearby-my-location) this is what i have come up with.

in onLocationChanged, this is what i do:

```
private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        this.myItemizedOverlay.clear();
        this.nonPlayerItemizedOverlay.clear();
        this.mapOverlays.clear();
        // Update my map location.
        Double latitude = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
        Double longitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(),
                longitude.intValue());

        CustomOverlayItem pcOverlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(geoPoint,
                "", "", "");

        this.mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);

        this.myItemizedOverlay.setLocation(location);
        this.myItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(pcOverlayItem);
        this.mapOverlays.add(this.myItemizedOverlay);

        // Everytime i get a new location i generate random non player
        // characters near my location
        int numberOfNonPlayers = new Random().nextInt(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNonPlayers; i++) {
            int radius = (int) this.myMapView.getProjection()
                    .metersToEquatorPixels(200);
            double lowerLimit = -1;
            double upperLimit = 1;

            Double newLatitude = location.getLatitude()
                    * 1E6
                    + (radius * (lowerLimit + (Math.random() * ((upperLimit - lowerLimit) + 1))));
            Double newLongitude = location.getLongitude()
                    * 1E6
                    + (radius * (lowerLimit + (Math.random() * ((upperLimit - lowerLimit) + 1))));

            GeoPoint geoPoint2 = new GeoPoint(newLatitude.intValue(),
                    newLongitude.intValue());

            CustomOverlayItem npcOverlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(
                    geoPoint2, "", "", "");

            Location newLocation = new Location("npc " + i);
            newLocation.setLatitude(newLatitude);
            newLocation.setLongitude(newLongitude);

            this.nonPlayerItemizedOverlay = new NonPlayerItemizedOverlay(
                    this.nonPlayerDrawable, this.myMapView);
            this.nonPlayerItemizedOverlay.setLocation(newLocation);
            this.nonPlayerItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(npcOverlayItem);
            this.mapOverlays.add(this.nonPlayerItemizedOverlay);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my NonPlayerItemizedOverlay class:

```
public class NonPlayerItemizedOverlay extends BaseItemizedOverlay {

public NonPlayerItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(defaultMarker, mapView);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private Location location;

public static int metersToRadius(float meters, MapView map, double latitude) {
    return (int) (map.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(meters) * (1 / Math
            .cos(Math.toRadians(latitude))));
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    if (shadow == false) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        // Get the current location
        Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(),
                longitude.intValue());

        // Convert the location to screen pixels
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);

        // int radius = metersToRadius(30, mapView, latitude);
        int radius = (int) mapView.getProjection()
                .metersToEquatorPixels(50);

        RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - radius, point.y - radius, point.x
                + radius, point.y + radius);

        // Setup the paint
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

        paint.setColor(0xffE62020);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);

        paint.setColor(0x18E62020);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
    }
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

And my MyItemizedOverlay class:

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends BaseItemizedOverlay {

public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(defaultMarker, mapView);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private Location location;

public static int metersToRadius(float meters, MapView map, double latitude) {
    return (int) (map.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(meters) * (1 / Math
            .cos(Math.toRadians(latitude))));
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    if (shadow == false) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        // Get the current location
        Double latitude = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
        Double longitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(),
                longitude.intValue());

        // Convert the location to screen pixels
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);

        // int radius = metersToRadius(100, mapView, latitude);
        int radius = (int) mapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(
                200);

        RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - radius, point.y - radius, point.x
                + radius, point.y + radius);

        // Setup the paint
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

        paint.setColor(0xff6666ff);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);

        paint.setColor(0x186666ff);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
    }
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

The thing is that something weird is happening because all the random locations are too near of my location center, it seems that the formula does not cover the whole radius and i think that distances are not in real meters.

Any idea of what could be wrong with my formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm no expert on map projections, but these guys might be: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you Tony, that link really helped me. If you write a response with it i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions regarding **map projections** and **coordinate calculations**, this SE site could be helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com (Geographic Information Systems).

Answer (score 0):

To be sure use the distanceTo() formula of location class.You can do it this way:

```
double distance  = a.distanceTo(b);
```

where a and b are Location objects.

Comment: Thank you. After checking, distances are in real meters. Now it seems that i am not creating locations using the whole radius, just like half of it